# Routing cause Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I tried to and practice some examples and met a very tricky error. I spent a couple of hours to figure out RangeError,but I failed to overcome it. Can anyone help me get out from this trap?

In app.js

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
  {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
      }).
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'add-order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'show-orders.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
  }]);

sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope) {

  $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function($scope) {

  $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

});
```

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
    <h1>weclome to test!</h1>
<body ng-app="phonecatApp" >
<div ng-view></div>

<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="static/app.js"></script>   
</body>


</html>
```

In add_order.html

```
<h2>Add New Order</h2>

{{ message }}
```

In show_order.html

```
<h2>Show Orders</h2>

{{ message }}
```

In addition, the wrong source directory of folder that store js and html files cause the RangeError?

This is error that shows in chrome console
[image]

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @SteamDev I add a screenshot of my error. I can not stop the program unless kill it.

Comment: You're recursively calling some function. We cannot determine what the problem is until you post more of your code. The easiest thing for you to do is start stripping out pieces until you have a reproducible test case. Chances are, you'll come across the recursion while doing this exercise.

Comment: @ Adam I use Django as my backend server. The index.html is rendered by Django template. Could it be a suspected target？

Answer (score 5):

I think you are browsing to /, which is probably index.html, which includes app.js, which will need index.html due to the route, which will require app.js, etc... You may need to put your / template in another html file (let's call it home.html), and change the template for / to home.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Then I tried with putting 'script' tags to 'head' tag. It works fine now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="static/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="phonecatApp" >
    <h1>weclome to test!</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the routing scripts in to a different file.

```js
angular.module('phonecatApp').config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
  {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
      }).
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'add-order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'show-orders.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
  }]);
```

then refer it in your index file may be like :

```html
<script src="static/router.js"></script>
```

that should fix it.

Comment: sorry mistakenly posted the whole code while correcting the router reference to index file :P

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem/ error. What worked for me was I used the routes with <kbd>#</kbd> . i.e I removes this part from `app.js`

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
});
```